# No build method inside Web3j class

Tags: web3j

I'm trying to initialize web3j with following code:

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = null;
try {
    web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().sendAsync().get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
```

Also I've added as per [manual](https://docs.web3j.io/getting_started.html) dependency

```
compile ('org.web3j:core-android:2.2.1')
```

But android studio refuses to compile that.It says `cannot resolve method`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed at the bottom of the manual following text:

> Note: for Android use:
>
> Web3j web3 = Web3jFactory.build(new HttpService()); // defaults to http://localhost:8545/

However I'm still unable to compile it due to this exception:

> Java7Support: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added

Comment: fixed by changing java_home path in system variables